Production issue on mail server sending in springboot project
root@api:~# tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 62 common frames omitted

2024-07-20 07:07:10.890 DEBUG 561029 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for POST "/global/error", parameters={}

I have an Springboot project which has been deployed on VPS server it is running in local tomcat but not running in server because of authentication issue if anyone knows about this issue reach me out

the little bit of stacktrace that you have provided doesn't provide enough info, please add complete stacktrace
